# Is there a way to recover my applications from Genymotion virtual machine?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, genymotion

I was working on an Android application and the project files got accidentally deleted from my computer but I still have the application on more than one virtual machine (Genymotion). Is there any way to restore these files (code, images, ...)?

I tried finding the data stored on the virtual machine but all I found was the system disk and data disk (but both in .vmdk format). And tried accessing the files in the data disk but still couldn't.

Comment: Do you want to say you deleted the whole project accidentally?

Comment: The whole partition got deleted, accidentally...

Comment: what is the mean of partition?

Comment: By definition, it's a defined storage space on a hard drive :)

Comment: @KhaledMohamed have you tried any tools to recover lost files?

Comment: Use Hard drive recovery app to recover your data

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException the thing is that recovery tools, in my case, are pretty much useless. Because the partition previously owned by Windows got deleted while I was installing Ubuntu. So now the data is pretty much lost, I think.

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException I was hoping to recover the data from the Genymotion virtual machine.

Comment: @KhaledAbdrabo right. The data probably got overwritten... In that case, the only way would be to get it from the Genymotion VM. I don't have a clue where to start...